# l have NaN which are not NaN in my CSV file due to comma in a column considered as delimiter which is not

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

l have a strange scenario where `non NaN` values are represented by `#####`  but when l click on the cell of `####` l get the value. However when l manipulate my data l got the following error :

```
  img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[3]),int(coords[0]):int(coords[1])]
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Because it reads some cell as `NaN`

how can l avoid that ?
Here is my csv file

[image]

in the following picture look at te line `139 cell C` when l click on that cell l get the real value on the top right corner

[image]

l increased the width of the column l don't have any `####` in my csv file.
However when l read my csv file as follow :

```
npa=np.genfromtxt(path_csv+"char.csv", delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=(2,3,4,5))

npa[:280]
array([[   38.,   104.,  2456.,  2492.],
       [   40.,   102.,  2442.,  2448.],
       [   40.,   100.,  2402.,  2410.],
       ..., 
       [ 1473.,  1482.,   153.,   177.],
       [   nan,  1491.,  1494.,   172.],
       [ 1508.,  1517.,   159.,   177.]])
```

l get strangely one `NaN` value `(npa[278])`

```
[   nan,  1491.,  1494.,   172.]
```

l noticed  in this value it is not reading the correct column.
the entire line is as follow  :

```
',' 1491    1494    172 181
```

rather writing :
 [ 1491.,  1494.,   172., 181.]
it writes :

```
[   nan,  1491.,  1494.,   172.]
```

which means it reads the first column which is a char `(',')` and left the last column.
l noticed that for each row with a char `','` for the rest it's ok

here how l read my csv :

```
npa=np.genfromtxt(path_csv+"char.csv", delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=(2,3,4,5))
```

l have  `delimiter=','` and in the first column l have some char which are `','`
the question is updated to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093100/considering-comma-in-a-cell-column-as-delimiter-but-its-not-how-to-differentia
```

thank you

Comment: It's an Excel feature, not a python issue. [### means the column is too narrow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-a-error-7e8008e3-7b38-46ed-ba50-a9ae6b9f0859)

Comment: Just increase the width of the `C` column and you'll see the values.

Comment: Open the CSV in something other than Excel. What you are looking at is MS trickery, not Pandas.

Comment: please see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Excel question, and your problem happens because Excel has no space to display the value. Increase the column width of C and you'll be fine.

Comment: l solved the problem by changing genfromtxt with pandas dataframe